# PHP / AJAX Concurrent Session Misbehaving only in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-chrome, session

TL;DR. The interesting piece without having to wade through the JS first: I'm incrementing a session counter, yet different requests are seeing the same value. This is only an issue in Chrome. In Firefox and Internet Explorer, every request sees a unique value.

I am trying to hit a web page (to process data) a bunch of times until I get a 204 HTTP code. I can do one ajax call at a time, by having the ajax call itself on success, and stopping on 204.

Since I want to do them faster, I have multiple "threads" in js all doing that. By that I mean multiple identical ajax calls are created, and they all start another one when they are completed, stopping on the 204 code.

My relevant js looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    // "thread" id
    var counter = 1;

    // run 3 "threads"
    generateThreads(3);

    function generateThreads(num) {
        if (num <= 0)
            return;

        doNextItem(counter++);

        // Pause before starting the next thread
        setTimeout(function() {
                generateThreads(num-1);
            },
            50);
    }

    function doNextItem(thread) {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            statusCode: {
                200: function(data) {
                    logItem(data, thread);
                    doNextItem(thread); // call itself on the same thread

                },
                204: function(data) {
                    finished(); // done, don't recurse, end the thread
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then in PHP, I'm incrementing an integer stored in Session and returning 204 when it is over a cutoff.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["nums"]))
{
    $_SESSION["nums"] = 0;
}
else if ($_SESSION["nums"] > 10) {
    http_response_code(204);
    die();
}
echo json_encode(array("num" => $_SESSION["nums"]++));
```

And then the weird part comes when I run it. logItem() in the javascript just prints to the console the thread id, then the number from php.

**Chrome:**

```
1: 0 
2: 0 
2: 1 
1: 1 
3: 1 
2: 2 
1: 2 
3: 2 
1: 3 
2: 3 
3: 3 
3: 4 
1: 4 
2: 4 
3: 5 
2: 5 
1: 5 
2: 6 
3: 6 
1: 6 
1: 7 
2: 7 
3: 7 
1: 8 
3: 8 
2: 8 
1: 9 
2: 9 
3: 9 
2: 10
1: 10
3: 10
```

**Firefox / IE**

```
1: 0
2: 1
3: 2
1: 3
2: 4
3: 5
1: 6
2: 7
3: 8
1: 9
2: 10
3: 11
1: 12
2: 13
3: 14
1: 15
2: 16 
3: 17 
1: 18  
2: 19 
3: 20
```

Why is chrome giving me the repeated values?

**UPDATE**

Something that is really fishy is that the number of duplicates for each number is exactly equal to the number of ajax calls that are going at the same time. Never less, never more, but exactly. If I run 6 ajax calls at the same time, they all get the same amount. If this was a timing issue, it wouldn't be that consistent, especially because I offset the different ajax calls from each other. This implies to me that it is a javascript issue, not necessarily only a php issue as it appeared before.

**HUGE GAME CHANGER OF AN UPDATE**
This is only an issue in Chrome. Doesn't happen in firefox or Internet Explorer. In Firefox and IE, every request gets a new value of the counter. Clearly this is a client side problem. Doing a little more research with this info brings up a lot of things about invalid requests doing a redirect that kills the session. Specifically a common scenario with the favicon.ico. All of my requests result in a success, and my favicon.ico is successfully loaded as well.

Comment: At the time you are sending the session has not yet been set or modified since the end of the previous execution thread will not occur until after all 3 threads are complete. In other words, your just doing the same thing 3 times assyncronously. The variable has not changed. Try a larger interval in your setTimeout()

Comment: I'm just going to guess you're firing off your ajax calls too quickly. Each one is probably hitting the php page before the server has updated the $_SESSION. Also, javascript is single threaded, so your thread concept seems artificial; presently your 'threads' will never execute concurrently, unless you plan to swap them out with web workers at some point https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers Also, your code example is a strange mixing of concerns: why even have PHP store a value when you could easily track the value in Javascript?

Comment: @zgr024: All the other links on the web state that session_start() locks access to the session file, so no other requests to session with that session id happen concurrently.

Comment: @MarkFox: Obviously I'm not going to just be incrementing a counter in the php. This is a dumbed down example, I'm doing something more complex, this is just an example to show the issue.

Comment: Also, my "threads" are only ajax calls. So I'm doing 3 ajax calls concurrently, and they restart as soon as they are completed until they get 204 back. This is totally fine to do in javascript, and is just a similar definition to threading.

Comment: Good point, I see that you're working towards a webworker like approach. Your requests are concurrent though Javascript is executing them sequentially. I don't know what you're working towards but considering designing so that either the client or server is holding all of the model logic. It seems like in your case you'd want to put it on the server. For instance you're currently assuming each AJAX message will hit the server in order, but that's not guaranteed, especially depending on the topography of the network path.

Comment: @MarkFox, I'm not assuming that each AJAX message will hit in order. They can hit in any order, I just assume that they will all get different values of session because everywhere online says that Sessions are locked for each user at session_start() so it should be impossible for multiple requests with the same session id to get the same value. But that doesn't seem to be happening, so I'm trying to find a solution. I should take a look at webworkers, but since it's on the server, I don't think that would solve it.

Comment: OK, now I see it. Sorry, I had read it totally wrong initially. As debugging step, time stamping each call and response might be helpful next step. Interested to see what you discover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome is caching the response because you're sending the same request multiple times within a short timeframe. Forcing the ajax call to not cache the response should solve your problem. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    cache: false,
    statusCode: {
...
```

Comment: I am having a problem with session with php. The problem is session returning different value of other users. This answer gives me an idea to solve. But I don't use this code I rather follow instructions here http://spacebug.com/solving_browser_caching_problem_of_ajax-html/. But again your answer is very helpful